# Python websocket for real time processing

Tags: python, elasticsearch, websocket, apache-flink

I've create a python script that opens a websocket to get trade orders and upload them to the elasticsearch cluster so that I can perform near real time analytics. I wanted to get some response on my code below or if there is a better way to do this with different code set or tool such as logstash or Apache flink.

```
from websocket import create_connection
import json

ws = create_connection('wss://ws-feed.gdax.com')
sub = json.dumps({"type": "subscribe", "product_id": "LTC-USD"})
ws.send(sub)

while True:
    result = json.loads(ws.recv())
    elastic_upload(result) #post data to elasticsearch cluster


ws.close()
```

Thanks!